# is there any alternative solution for renderers in log4j2?

Tags: java, xml, log4j, log4j2

I was using **log4j 1.x** earlier and majorly using Renderers in **log4j.xml** for customization printing.

Overriding **ObjectRenderer**'s **doRender()** in my java code like below in MessageRenderer.java overrding **ObjectRenderer**:

```
    public String doRender(Object o) {

    MessageLoggingContext loggingContext = (MessageLoggingContext) o;
    AbstractMessage message = loggingContext.getMessage();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(512);
    sb.append(message.isIncoming() ? "T:" : "F:").append("[").append(loggingContext.getConnectionID()).append(",")
            .append(
                    loggingContext.getSessionKey()).append(",").append(loggingContext.getAccountName())
            .append("]:"); 
     return sb.toString();
    }


    Inside log4j.xml :

    <renderer renderedClass="com.common.service.log4j.MessageLoggingContext" 
    renderingClass="com.common.service.log4j.MessageRenderer" />
```

Answer (score 0):

From the above example, it seems that you want to render some text.

One API : [TextRenderer](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/pattern/TextRenderer.html) should be useful for your use case.

```
void render(String input,
        StringBuilder output,
        String styleName)
```

> Renders input text to an output.
> Parameters:
> input - The input
> output - The output
> styleName - The style name to use to render the input on the output.

```
HtmlTextRenderer, JAnsiTextRenderer, PlainTextRenderer
```

are different types of renderers.